# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Comment System showing from SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, foreach, comments

I am creating a comment system for my website, and I am linking the comment to the article ID. Each comment has its own id in an increment order, but different comments can have the same article ID.

Here is the area the on my template form the error is being thrown:

```
<h1>Comments</h1>
<ul id="headlines" class="archive">

<?php foreach ($craps['comments'] as $comment ) { ?>

<li>
<h2>
<span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F Y', $comment->publicationDate)?></span>
</h2>
<p class="summary">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $comment->content )?>
</p>
</li>

<?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Here is the section of my index page with the setting of the variables like the array and data that the php for loop is using:

```
function viewArticle() {
if ( !isset($_GET["articleId"]) || !$_GET["articleId"] ) {
homepage();
return;
}
$results = array();
$results['article'] = Article::getById( (int)$_GET["articleId"] );
$results['pageTitle'] = $results['article']->title . " | Gaming News";


$craps = array();
$data = Comment::getList( (int)$_GET["articleId"]);
$craps['comments'] = $data['craps'];
require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/viewArticle.php" );
}
```

this is where the system is pulling the data from the database with (it is in my Comment.php):

```
public static function getList( $art, $order="publicationDate DESC", $numRows=10000 ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS           publicationDate FROM comments WHERE articleid = :art 
    ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":art", $art, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $comment = new Comment( $row );
  $list[] = $comment;
}
}
```

I would really appreciate the help. This the last error i have before the comments in the test system are displayed.

here is the new get list code :

```
public static function getList( $art, $order="publicationDate DESC", $numRows=10000 ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS      publicationDate FROM comments WHERE articleid = :art ORDER BY :order LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":art", $art, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":order", $order, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $comment = new Comment( $row );
  $list[] = $comment;
}
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `return $list;` from `getList()` so `$craps['comments']` is null. (`$data` is null)

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using the proper method (PDO bindings and prepared statements), but at the same time you the deprecated function mysql_escape_string()?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra I'm guessing that was because you cannot bind a PDO parameter as a column name into the `ORDER BY`, but at the same time, `mysql_escape_string()` will result in an empty string if there's no active connection via `mysql_connect()`.  It cannot just be used independently.

Comment: First thing's first: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and setup your PDO object to do something with errors (like throw an exception) - it silently ignores them by default. What you'll likely find is a syntax error at the `ORDER BY` due to the inappropriate use of `mysql_escape_string()` mentioned earlier.

Comment: so what would i have to enter to fix it, I'm pretty novice at php

Comment: Start by hard-coding the `ORDER BY` clause and get your query to run. Use `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to get PDO throwing useful errors.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, oh I see what you're saying, totally missed that. Even then, I'm not sure why you'd want to escape a table name in the first place..any ideas on that one? I've never seen that done before.

In any case, OP, don't escape the string for a table name. If you're letting users set the table name, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: You can supply the table name as input, but you should not accept _just any_ input and attempt to escape it. Instead, make an array of acceptable values for `$order` and then test that the input value is in that array. If it isn't, you got bad input and don't want to execute the query with it.

Comment: I recoded the section and there is no connection error or anything like that. It is still throwing the error for this line: <?php foreach ($craps['comments'] as $comment ) { ?>

Comment: Post your current code.  There may not be a connection error, but there might be a query error. (there is certain to be one if `mysql_escape_string()` is still present)

Comment: i am getting a new error tho, Notice: Undefined index: craps in line 37 which is : $craps['comments'] = $data['craps'];

Comment: i put the new code for get list in the question itself

Comment: no matter what i get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CollegeMagnum/Gaming_News/templates/viewArticle.php on line 19, idk if its a sql error or a code error

Comment: here was the error i need to fix the return and this was missing code to go in get list        return ( array ( "craps" => $list));